# Por que o Value no Spring MVC necessita de asterisco?

Tags: java, mvc, spring, spring-mvc, wildcard

Por que eu preciso colocar `*` no value quando já não há mais nada? Digo, antes de usar Spring MVC funcionava sem problemas somente como `/planilha/`.

O `getPlanilha` funciona corretamente mas se ele possuir o mesmo `RequestMethod` e `consumes` vai executar o `create` ? Já que ambos vão ter `/planilha/QualquerCoisa` SOMENTE por causa do asterisco.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/planilha/**", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public String create(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String jsonStr) {...}

@RequestMapping(value = "/planilha/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPlanilha(@PathVariable("id") String id) {...}
```

De acordo com a documentação:

> `?` matches one character
>   `*` matches zero or more characters
>   `**` matches zero or more 'directories' in a path.

Entendi a funcionalidade mas a dúvida se irá executar o create permanece.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bom, vamos por parte.

> Por que eu preciso colocar * no value quando já não há mais nada?

Na verdade não precisa. Você pode deixar apenas `planilha/` OU `planilha`, por exemplo. Uma chamada POST em `http://{host}:{porta}/{contexto}/planilha/` OU `http://{host}:{porta}/{contexto}/planilha`, respectivamente, e `Content-Type` igual a `application/json` irá funcionar.

> antes de usar Spring MVC funcionava sem problemas somente como `/planilha/`.

Acredito que, provavelmente, você esteja referindo-se a servlets, `@WebServlet("/planilha/")` ou mapeamento no `web.xml`, certo? Pois bem, vide exemplo acima =)

> O `getPlanilha` funciona corretamente mas se ele possuir o mesmo `RequestMethod` e `consumes` vai executar o create?

Por `possuir o mesmo RequestMethod e consumes` acredito que esteja referindo-se aos do método `create`. Então, sim, caso o método HTTP seja `POST` e exista no header da requisição um `Content-Type=application/json`, será o método `create` a ser chamado. Por que? Por que não existe outro mapeamento mais específico que ele que atende a estas exigências. Se, por outro lado, eu possuísse um mapeamento como este:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/planilha/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public String newCreate(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody String jsonStr) {...}
```

Seria `newCreate` a ser executado, por ser o mapeamento mais específico existente.

A [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison) do Spring MVC é bastante clara quanto a especificidade dos padrões de URL.

> - The **default mapping pattern** `/**` is less specific than any other pattern. For example `/api/{a}/{b}/{c}` is more specific.
> - A **prefix pattern** such as `/public/**` is less specific than any other pattern that doesn’t contain double wildcards. For example `/public/path3/{a}/{b}/{c}` is more specific.

Você pode ver mais sobre os padrões utilizados no matcher utilizado pelo spring, chamado [`AntPathMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html).

Agora, para exemplificar, vamos considerar algumas requisições baseando no mapeamento do seu controller. Considere assim:

```java
@Controller
public class PlanilhaController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PlanilhaController.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/planilha/**", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public String create(final HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody final String json) {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("PlanilhaController#create --> called create with json '%s'", json));
        LOGGER.info(String.format("PlanilhaController#create --> called create on path '%s'", request.getRequestURI()));
        return "page";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/planilha/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPlanilha(@PathVariable("id") final String id) {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("PlanilhaController#getPlanilha --> called getPlanilha with id '%s'", id));
        return "page";
    }

}
```

- Chamada GET em `http://{host}:{porta}/{contexto}/planilha/bruno` irá produzir este log:

  ```
  Apr 14, 2015 9:49:55 PM com.brunocesar.controller.PlanilhaController getPlanilha
  INFORMAÇÕES: PlanilhaController#getPlanilha --> called getPlanilha with id 'bruno'
  ```
- Chamada GET em `http://{host}:{porta}/{contexto}/planilha/bruno/cesar` irá produzir uma [`HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.html) com um log tipo isto:

  ```
  Apr 14, 2015 9:50:09 PM com.brunocesar.controller.ControllerErrorHandler processException
  ADVERTÊNCIA: ControllerErrorHandler#processException --> message: 'Request method 'GET' not supported
  ```
- Chamada POST e `Content-Type` igual a `application/json` em `http://{host}:{porta}/{contexto}/planilha/` irá produzir log mais ou menos assim:

  ```
  Apr 14, 2015 9:50:36 PM com.brunocesar.controller.PlanilhaController create
  INFORMAÇÕES: PlanilhaController#create --> called create with json '{"name":"bruno"}'
  Apr 14, 2015 9:50:36 PM com.brunocesar.controller.PlanilhaController create
  INFORMAÇÕES: PlanilhaController#create --> called create on path '/springmvc-sample/planilha/'
  ```
- Chamada POST e `Content-Type` igual a `application/json` em `http://{host}:{porta}/{contexto}/planilha` irá produzir log mais ou menos assim:

  ```
  Apr 14, 2015 9:51:22 PM com.brunocesar.controller.PlanilhaController create
  INFORMAÇÕES: PlanilhaController#create --> called create with json '{"name":"bruno"}'
  Apr 14, 2015 9:51:22 PM com.brunocesar.controller.PlanilhaController create
  INFORMAÇÕES: PlanilhaController#create --> called create on path '/springmvc-sample/planilha'
  ```
- Chamada POST e `Content-Type` igual a `application/json` em `http://{host}:{porta}/{contexto}/planilha/bruno` irá produzir log mais ou menos assim:

  ```
  Apr 14, 2015 9:52:10 PM com.brunocesar.controller.PlanilhaController create
  INFORMAÇÕES: PlanilhaController#create --> called create with json '{"name":"bruno"}'
  Apr 14, 2015 9:52:10 PM com.brunocesar.controller.PlanilhaController create
  INFORMAÇÕES: PlanilhaController#create --> called create on path '/springmvc-sample/planilha/bruno'
  ```
- Chamada POST e `Content-Type` igual a `application/xml` em `http://{host}:{porta}/{contexto}/planilha/bruno` irá produzir uma [`HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.html) com um log mais ou menos assim:

  ```
  Apr 14, 2015 9:52:45 PM com.brunocesar.controller.ControllerErrorHandler processException
  ADVERTÊNCIA: ControllerErrorHandler#processException --> message: 'Content type 'application/xml' not supported
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que seja apenas uma convenção do Web MVC. No meu entender, ao fazer um `/planilha/` no Web MVC você pode subentender que deve haver algo depois do último `/`, por isto a necessidade de especificar como será o match após o `/`.

Creio que o mais adequado seria usar apenas `/planilha` (sem a última `/`). Assim, ao fazer apenas `/planilha` ele irá executar o create e ao fazer `/planilha/QualquerCoisa` fará o getPlanilha

Comment: Bom, isto não pode ser tratado de forma tão simples. Você precisa ver que a semântica dos mapeamentos são diferentes, procure considerar isto na sua resposta.